# How to validate the invoice invoice Odoo 10?

Tags: php, odoo-10

I can't validate the invoice

I found the method somewhere but it doesn't work...

This method twice changes Status: Open -> PAID; Draft -> PAID :(
I need to change the status to "open". In other words I need to validate invoice.

Help me please and tell me where Where can I get information about those methods?

```
$res = $model->execute_kw(
  $db,
  $uid,
  $password,
  'account.invoice',
  'invoice_validate',
  [5244]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using 'action_invoice_open' function instead of 'invoice_validate'

Comment: Thanks! But Where can I find this method? How do you know about it?